# select query or any query of my mysql did not work in hostgator

Tags: php, mysql

The code is working in the localhost server but did not work when I upload the code in HostGator 
  server. I have also checked my php version. please someone help me.

```
sql=";$sql="SELECT  `pass`,`username` FROM `userdetails` WHERE `email`='$email'";
$result=$conn->query($sql);
```

after this line my code did not work

```
  if($result->num_rows > 0){  
    //from here my code did not work
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Now that it has been formatted it is easy to see an error at the very beginning of the PHP - `sql=";$sql=.....` etc - can you confirm if this is in your actual code or just from pasting the code here?

Comment: The code you're showing is a syntax error and won't work on any system.  Once that's corrected, it's also wide open to SQL injection so the query could very easily be failing.  Where are you checking for errors from the query?  The code you're indicating "did not work" is inside an `if` block, what have you done to confirm that the condition isn't simply `false`?